# Why is TPU on Google Colab in PyTorch not being detected?

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am using google colab and PyTorch. I set my hardware accelerator to TPU.

This line of code shows that no cuda device is being detected:

```
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device)
```

Answer (score 1):

TPUs are not CUDA devices. Please take a look at this [Colab](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/pytorch/xla/blob/master/contrib/colab/getting-started.ipynb)that shows how to run some PyTorch code on TPUs.